# How to solve port already in use error in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a ReactApp that is currently running on port **3000**.

Now, when I started another NextJS App and decided to test it out, it gives the error:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3000

This makes no sense. If it were regular ReactJS, ReactJS would immediately ask me if they should use another port, the moment I select **Yes** ReactJS will automatically switch to another port and start the application. Why can't NextJS follow same approach instead of failing immediately.

I don't expect that I would now have to kill my ReactApp running on port **3000** just so NextApp can run.

Is there a way around this?

Thank you.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your `next` server on another port.

Try doing this in `package.json`

```
 "scripts": { 
       "dev": "next -p 8080" 
},
```

8080 => The port you want.